# Is there any way to trigger a thread dump for WebLogic server as soon as the server goes into a low thread count state?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, thread-dump

we have a WebLogic setup that has been giving us some problems.

We have a monitoring tool called HP BAC that helps us visualize the state of the servers, and we tie this tool with the Java Thread Dump utility such that when there is a low thread count situation, a thread dump will be captured.

There are situations where the server goes into a low thread count state, and we are uncertain why because all our efforts to find out - through thread dumps especially seems futile.

Given the "state of art", our thread dump capture is always triggered late / after, and always never capture thread dump useful for our investigation.

I would like to check how the rest of you guys have put in place such monitoring efforts?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest [WLST](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/using_WLST.html)

Write a WLST script which hooks into the running server and gets the active thread count at regular intervals. (say 30 seconds)

If your active thread count goes below your pre-configured threshold, fire the `kill - 3` and get the thread dump.

Some examples

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5423

http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.com/2009/04/wlst-thread-count.html

Answer (score 5):

The WebLogic Diagnostic Image includes a thread dump and can be automatically fired upon certain JMX metric thresholds being crossed by configuring a Watch and corresponding Notification in a WebLogic Diagnostic Framwork (WLDF) System Module that is targeted at your server.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13714/config_diag_images.htm
I created a youtube recording showing how this is done.
http://www.youtube.com/embed/QNtON5dcRTc?hd=1
http://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/create_weblogic_diagnostic_image_with

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the below WLST script which would give your the following feature

1. **Ready To Use:** The Script is ready to use, it means you need not to
       edit anything in the WLST script except the email address in
       line-32. Flexibility: You need to just change the values present in
       “domains.properties” file like how many Thread Dumps you want to
       collect when the issue occurs.
2. **E-Mail Alert**: The Administrator will get to know regarding the issue
      via an E-Mail alert immediately.
3. **Thread Dumps In Mail:** The complete Thread Dumps will we sent to the
       Administrator via the E-Mail so need not to worry about collecting
       the Thread Dumps.
4. **Independent Script:** This WLST script can run independently without
       the help of any Cron-Job utility provided by the operating System
       (But it can be associated with the Cron-Job utility as well) So it
       provides more flexibility to the Administrators.

Topic: **Sending Email Alert For Stuck Threads With Thread Dumps**

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5582

Regards,
Ravish Mody | Admin @ Middleware Magic